# Setting a window background behind AlertDialog removes dialog centering

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog

I'm creating an AlertDialog with customized view and window background. Setting a ColorDrawable works as expected, but setting a BitmapDrawable from resources makes the dialog appear right at the top of the screen (instead of centered). (Note: I'm talking of the background **behind** the dialog (normally a transparent grey, not the dialog's background itself!)

Dialog background (@drawable/dialog_bg):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/white" />
    <corners android:radius="10dp" />
</shape>
```

Dialog layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/dialog_bg"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- dialog contents -->

</LinearLayout>
```

Code to show dialog with ColorDrawable: **-> works**

```
private void showDialog() {
    final AlertDialog dialog;
    @SuppressLint("InflateParams") final ViewGroup dialogView = (ViewGroup) activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.my_dialog, null);
    dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity).setView(dialogView).create();
    // this works:
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    dialog.show();
}
```

Code to show dialog with BitmapDrawable from resources (loading a simple PNG): **-> removes centering**

```
private void showDialog() {
    final AlertDialog dialog;
    @SuppressLint("InflateParams") final ViewGroup dialogView = (ViewGroup) activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.my_dialog, null);
    dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity).setView(dialogView).create();
    // this sets the background, but un-centers the dialog:
    BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(activity.getResources(), R.drawable.my_bg, null);
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
    dialog.show();
}
```

Setting a ColorDrawable works as expected: The background behind the Dialog is colored and the dialog is still centered on screen.
Setting a BitmapDrawable does not work: The background is set but the dialog is moved to the top of the screen.

Things that also didn't work:

- loading the drawable with `ContextCompat.getDrawable()` (which is the same as `ResourcesCompat.getDrawable()` with the current theme instead of null)
- using DisplayMetrics and `dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().y` (and `.x` respectively) to calculate margins myself: `(height - y) / 2` -> just returns the "normal" dialog margin
- setting the gravity to CENTER on either `dialog.getWindow().setGravity()` or `dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().gravity` -> this just doesn't change anything
- setting the gravity to FILL on either `dialog.getWindow().setGravity()` or `dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().gravity` -> this removes dialog margins, but still at the top (even further at the top and left, as margins are removed)

So, does anybody know how to set a background from PNG **behind** the dialog and keeping its centering on the screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I just solved this issue, although I have to admit it's *a bit* hacky.

---

First, I **disabled fading** behind the dialog

```
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
dialog.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
```

and manually "faded" the activity by adding a view to it, **overlaying the activity** with semi-transparent black:

```
final ViewGroup dimBackgroundView = new FrameLayout(activity);
float dimAlpha = 0.5f;
dimBackgroundView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
dimBackgroundView.setAlpha(dimAlpha);
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
activityLayout.addView(dimBackgroundView, params);
```

This also requires me to manually **darken the statusbar** on supporting devices (SDK 21+):

```
final int statusBarColor;
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    statusBarColor = activity.getWindow().getStatusBarColor();
    activity.getWindow().setStatusBarColor(
            Color.rgb((int) (Color.red(statusBarColor) + 255 * dimAlpha),
                    (int) (Color.green(statusBarColor) + 255 * dimAlpha),
                    (int) (Color.blue(statusBarColor) + 255 * dimAlpha)));
} else {
    statusBarColor = Color.BLACK;
}
```

Afterwards, I **added the intended background** *to the activity* (`dialogBgView` on top of the semi-transparent black view) and went on adding the dialog as normal.
Since I now added all these views to the activity, I need to **remove them on dialog dismissal**:

```
dialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
        // remove dim
        activityLayout.removeView(dimBackgroundView);
        // restore original statusbar color
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            activity.getWindow().setStatusBarColor(statusBarColor);
        }
        // remove background image
        activityLayout.removeView(dialogBgView);
    }
});
```

---

It works, but it's really not a nice solution. So if anyone discovers a better way, please feel free to post it here.

Answer (score 0):

We had WindowManger for Dialog to Specify custom window attributes:

*The layout params you give here should generally be from values previously retrieved with {@link #getAttributes()}; you probably do not want to blindly create and apply your own, **since this will blow away any values set by the framework that you are not interested in.***

Just add these property according to your requirement :

```
 /**
 * Retrieve the current window attributes associated with this panel.
 *
 * @return WindowManager.LayoutParams Either the existing window
 *         attributes object, or a freshly created one if there is none.
 */

 WindowManager.LayoutParams params = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
    params.gravity = Gravity.TOP;

 /**
 * Set the width and height layout parameters of the window.  The default
 * for both of these is MATCH_PARENT; you can change them to WRAP_CONTENT
 * or an absolute value to make a window that is not full-screen.
 *
 * @param width The desired layout width of the window.
 * @param height The desired layout height of the window.
 *
 * @see ViewGroup.LayoutParams#height
 * @see ViewGroup.LayoutParams#width
 */
    dialog.getWindow().setLayout((int) (getScreenWidth(activity)), ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.message_email_selected);
 /**
 * Specify custom window attributes.  <strong>PLEASE NOTE:</strong> the
 * layout params you give here should generally be from values previously
 * retrieved with {@link #getAttributes()}; you probably do not want to
 * blindly create and apply your own, since this will blow away any values
 * set by the framework that you are not interested in.
 *
 * @param a The new window attributes, which will completely override any
 *          current values.
 */
    dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(params);
```

As Example :

```
 final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
            WindowManager.LayoutParams params = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_view);
            //            dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(null);
            dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
            dialog.getWindow().setLayout(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(params);
            dialog.show();
//Access dialog views
 TextView txt_cancel = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.txt_cancel);
```

Comment: _"Just add these property according to your requirement"_ - as I already stated in the last paragraph of the question: I tried that and it didn't work. So maybe I'm missing some attributes but then this doesn't really help much.